# send methods do not update after changing zip code at checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods, zipcode

I have a problem checking out magento that I just don't know what to do. If the user goes to checkout and fills in the zip code, the shipping methods are not and do not appear, however, if I have a default magento method active as Flat rate it works, but I do not use it in store then there is no reason to be active. What happens with checkout, shouldn't it update methods every time user changes zip code? How can I solve this? Thank you in advance .

the translation for the error below is: "Sorry, no quote available for this order now"

[image]

Comment: Please, clarify which Shipping Method is not appearing. In case you mean table rates, then most likely you configured the rates incorrectly.

Comment: The shipping methods installed. As the store I'm developing is in Brazil, we bought some shipping modules, and they work perfectly in the cart, but the magento checkout doesn't update as in the image when I insert the zip code.

Comment: if i put the zip code, it just doesn't bring the shipping methods.